# How to create a link to the page with detailed information about the student

Tags: hyperlink, onenote-api

What I need - is to create a link from data that was retrieved from /classNotebooks/students endpoint and make the query that, being supplied to the browser, would redirect the user to the page with detailed information about the student (or his/her profile, whatever). This is similar to how the 'clientUrl' and 'webUrl' from notebook entity do work, when you encode them and supply to browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create that page with that content via POST ~/sections/id/pages
2. The response of POST pages will contain a webUrl - use that

If you want a page to exist with that content, why not create it?